# SQLAlchemy Alembic Migration generate SQL scripts at revision step with --autogenerate

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

We use SQLAlchemy + Alembic to generate migrations as python code (default behaviour for Alembic).
We want to move from python to SQL scripts as it provides more control over the generated scripts.
It seems the command `revision --autogenerate` doesn't work with `--sql` option.
We don't want to use `updgrade --sql` option as it just spits the SQL script but doesn't track it or can't be subsequently used with `revision --autogenerate`
Is there a way to generate migrations as SQL scripts automatically?

Answer (score 2):

I've not seen a way to autogenerate new migrations as SQL, but we also wanted to keep our migrations in SQL and handle it this way:

We store each migration as "forward" and "backward" SQL files, with a timestamp and the revision in the name (the timestamp was added simply because we prefer the revisions to be sortable by filename).

We use a wrapper shell script that does several things:

- Runs `alembic` to generate the revision python file. We parse the output to get the revision string.
- Creates the SQL files in `<alembic_env>/migration_sql/` with names like `YYYYMMDD_HHMM_<revision>_forward.sql`

We then write the forward and backward (or upgrade/downgrade if you prefer) SQL DDL. We updated `<alembic_env>/script.py.mako` to generate the timestamp prefix and add it to the revision filename (so our revisions are `YYYYMMDD_HHMM_<revision>_<message_slug>.py`). The upgrade and downgrade functions in the revision file - which in a stock alembic revision use the `op.*` functions to describe migrations - now load the proper SQL file and execute it:

```py
def upgrade():
    upgrade_file_path = SCRIPTS_DIR / f"{revision_prefix}_{revision}_forward.sql"
    if not os.path.exists(upgrade_file_path):
        print(f"{upgrade_file_path} not found")
        raise Exception(f"{upgrade_file_path} not found, aborting migration")

    with open(upgrade_file_path, "r") as upgrade_file:
        sql = upgrade_file.read()
        op.execute(sql)
```

This took some doing to set up, but works well and also makes it easy to have a DBA review the migration code in a merge request before we deliver. Hope this helps.